# Bundle for notifications in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, notifications, bundle

I want to include notifications, e.g. for forum threads. A user shall retrieve notifications if there are any new posts to a forum thread. Another example would be the notifications on Facebook, e.g. where you're notified of new comments on your posts or pictures.

Is there a notification bundle for Symfony2 that you can recommend for implementing such a function?

I came up with the [Sonata NotificationBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/notification) but I am unsure if this is what I really need. When I look at the `usage examples` it looks as if this would provide a email notification function

```
// retrieve the notification backend
$backend = $container->get('sonata.notification.backend');

// create and publish a message
$backend->createAndPublish('mailer', array(
    'from' => array(
        'email' => 'no-reply@sonata-project.org',
        'name'  => 'No Reply'
    ),
    'to'   => array(
        'myuser@example.org' => 'My User',
        'myuser1@example.org' => 'My User 1',
    ),
    'message' => array(
        'html' => '<b>hello</b>',
        'text' => 'hello'
    ),
    'subject' => 'Contact form',
));
```

or a logging function

```
$this->get('sonata.notification.backend')->createAndPublish('logger', array(
    'level' => 'debug',
    'message' => 'Hello world!'
));
```

Can you confirm/recommend the usage of that bundle? Or can you recommend any other?

Comment: I'm not aware of a notification bundle, but I feel like it would have to be integrated with your bundle that contains the threads/messages. I use the FOSMessageBundle, and added events to send the user an email when certain messages are sent to them. I also make use of the function that outputs unread messages to highlight that the user has unread messages at the top of the page. You could expand on that with css to create a popup and show details of the message.

Comment: Interesting approach. Yet looking for a bundle, there must be something...

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel you come up with a bundle you recommand?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But if you come up with one, please post a link as a comment or answer. Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel did you manage to use any of the bundles?

Answer (score 3):

Good news:
**NotificationBundle from GeniusesOfSymfony**
https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/NotificationBundle

Proper documentation will probably be published soon.
(on-going discussion here: https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle/issues/4#issuecomment-81829513)

I've already tested a similar bundle created by them (WebSocketBundle) which also provides real-time-interaction and it works really great. The documentation is also very good.

I recommend that you "star" the project on github. You can also create an issue to ask about the current status of the project.

Comment: Looks interesting, I'll take a deeper look into it. I'm very curious about how that Bundle develops!

Comment: Sadly they seem to run out of time! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm searching for the same library now, and also found https://github.com/namshi/notificator

Didn't use it yet, but it has 130 stars today, so probably will try it.

Comment: That looks very promising. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with sonata notification bundle.

You will need to create custom consumer class as described here

https://sonata-project.org/bundles/notification/3-x/doc/reference/usage.html#custom-consumer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Bundle: [NotificationsBundle](https://github.com/mradmrad/NotificationsBundle)
It's a simple implementation for [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) that provides a real time data proadcast.